# sql server CLR scalar function with default column name

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, clr, user-defined-functions

I was wondering, if there's any way to add a column names to my CLR scalar functions in Sql Server. I mean that after I run my query, I'd like to see a column with a result of this function already named with something custom instead of `(No column name)`.

I know that often functions are combined together, or I'd have to name them something different for other reason, but still - when you write a query with 30 columns, not having to punch in an alias for 20 of them would be nice.

So does anyone know a hack that would enable this?

It'd also be sweet to have this feature through some addin in SSMS (e.g. building dummy aliases from functions and columns used in calculation, like "datediff_startdate_enddate"). I tried to find a ready solution to this, but with no effect. Any hints?

Edit:
Some people asked me about code example. I don't think this would help much, but here it is:

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ClrFunctions
{
    public class RegexFunctions
    {

        public static SqlBoolean clrIsMatch(SqlString strInput, SqlString strPattern)
        {
            if (strPattern.IsNull || strInput.IsNull)
            {
                return SqlBoolean.False;
            }
            return (SqlBoolean)Regex.IsMatch(strInput.Value, strPattern.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        }
    }
}
```

T-SQL:

```
Create Assembly ClrFunctions From 'C:\CLR\ClrFunctions.dll' 
GO

Create Function dbo.clrIsMatch(
    @strInput As nvarchar(4000),
    @strPattern As nvarchar(255)
)
Returns Bit
As External Name [ClrFunctions].[ClrFunctions.RegexFunctions].[clrIsMatch]
GO
```

And this is my wish-to-be-possible call of this function in T-SQL and expected result:

```
select 
    txt, dbo.clrIsMatch(txt,'[0-9]+') 
from (
    select 'some 123 text' as txt union all 
    select 'no numbers here' union all 
    select 'numbers 456 again'
) x
```

Result already has a column name, without the need to add alias in T-SQL:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a specific example would help to get some responses: can you show a minimal example of code? The [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx) in MSDN suggest that CLR functions do (or can) provide columns names in their result sets.

Comment: You can add column names for table-valued functions, but that's not what I mean. I want to provide column name for scalar functions. But thank you for your comment.

Comment: OK, since you never used the word "scalar" that wasn't obvious, although as far as I know scalar functions never have column aliases in SQL Server. They don't return columns, after all. But I've edited your question title and tags to hopefully make the question clearer and get some better responses.

Comment: Ok, I should've pointed out that I mean scalar functions. But after your edit it now looks like I don't know how to add an alias to a column in T-SQL :). C# is crucial here, there >might< be a way to get around this. I'll start a bounty tomorrow, this should help with responses :).

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT dbo.f()` return a value with `(No column name)` whether it's a TSQL or CLR function? That's why I suggested posting some sample code to make it as clear as possible how you're calling the functions and what you expect.

Comment: Did you happen to go through this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596101404-02-12.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, "No."  A scalar function (CLR or not) just returns a value.

"User-defined scalar functions return a single data value of the type defined in the RETURNS clause." per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

As you suggested, the correct solution is adding an alias where you use the function.

```
SELECT ABS(a.Position - b.Position) AS Distance
    FROM sch.Tbl a
        INNER JOIN sch.Tbl b
            ON a.Key <= b.Key
;
```

And that doesn't change whether the function is a built-in, or a user-defined function, or a CLR function.

Comment: That's what the documentations says. I just think that using C# may open up new possibilities for a hack ;). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume somewhere you have a call to something like this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT SomeFunction();";
```

try this

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT SomeFunction() 'AliasForColumnNameYouWant';";
```

Not sure what you mean by 20 or 30 functions?

Are you saying that within Sql-Server there is some stored procedure or function calling 20 or 30 different scalar functions?

Or maybe the same function being called 20 or 30 times?

And are you combining the results into a returnable row or column of data?

Need code examples please.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I added code samples, hope this will clear thigs up a little. By "20 or 30 functions" I mean that if I need to write a query that uses clr functions (one function - one column), then I'd like to save time by not having to name every column in order to put them into temporary table (select * into #temp), because the names will already be there.

Answer (score -1):

Scalar function can be seen as the equivalent of an expression, and SQL do not request names for columns returned as the product of an expression. In SQL if you want to have an expression returned with a column name, you must aliases it in any of these two ways:

```
Select MyCol=Substring('123',2,1)
```

or

```
Select Substring('123',2,1) as MyCol
```

And if you want to reuse the alias at some other places in the query to build another expression (I prefer Alias=Expression)

```
Select MyExp2=MyExp+'2', MyExp3=MyExp+3, MyExp4
From 
  SomeTable
  CROSS APPLY (Select MyExp=Substring(SomeTable.SomeCol, 2, 1)) as MyExp
  -- below an example of reusing MyExp in another apply
  CROSS APPLY (Select MyExp4= MyExp + Substring(SomeTable.SomeCol, 4, 1)) as MyExp
```